# How do I remove a published Azure CDN Rules Engine

Tags: azure, cdn, rule-engine, azure-cdn

I published a rule created by rules engine and it got deployed. But how do I remove / cancel the policy or delete it ? I no longer need it as its causing continues redirect and my service is not accessible. Note that I am using `Premium Verizon` pricing tier

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.whitecdn.com/cdn/index.html#HRE/Policy.htm)

> Only a single policy per environment may be active at any given time.

You don't really remove it, you just overwrite it.
You can create a new draft, lock it, and deploy it on top of the existing one.

Also note that you can't have an empty policy.